# Another "What am I?" riddle

Tags: riddle

I am not holy, but I am.

Others are wrong to call me small, as I am everything combined.

When yelled, I become infinitely larger. Though my value only increases minimally.

I am the center, an origin even.

I am real and sometimes natural.

What am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are

> zero

but if so then I don't understand all the clues.

I am not holy, but I am.

> Not sure why exactly "not holy", but perhaps zero is holey because its numeral has a hole in and holy because its numeral looks like a halo. (One slightly tenuous explanation for "not holy": the word "naught", which of course means "nothing" or zero, used to mean something more like "wicked"; this is where the modern word "naughty" comes from but I think the meaning was a bit more serious than "naughty" is these days.)

Others are wrong to call me small, as I am everything combined.

> Zero is certainly called small. I'm not sure in what sense zero is "everything combined", though. (Perhaps a reference to the fact that every integer is a factor of zero, but that doesn't seem like quite the same thing.)

When yelled, I become infinitely larger. Though my value only increases minimally.

> 0! = zero factorial = 1 which is "infinitely larger" than zero multiplicatively, but greater than 0 additively by 1, which is "minimal" given that factorials are integers (if we ignore the gamma function...).

I am the center, an origin even.

> (0,0) on a graph, or 0 in the complex plane.

I am real and sometimes natural.

> Zero is a real number. Some mathematicians define the "natural numbers" as 0,1,2,... and some as 1,2,3,... .

Comment: You are correct, the second clue is easily the hardest. I'll accept your answer when the site lets me. It has a time delay.

Comment: everything combined: $\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty x $

Comment: Divergent integral. No value.

Comment: @Jaden Hint number 2 was meant to be all negative integers added to all positive integers. I.e. Zero. And for Gareth, hint 1 was "not holy" in the sense that zero was originally denounced by the church, but it is "holey" like you said.

Comment: Adding all the positive and all the negative integers is like Jasen's integral: you really can't do it. Oh well, never mind. ... Was zero really denounced by the church? When?